# PHP Calc distance between two points result in pixels

Tags: php, math

Lets say we have a square that has Height 500 x Width 500 pixels
Point one is located at H311:W447
Point two is located at H65:W156

How can I calculate the distance between these points in pixels using PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use [Pythagoras Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

```
$dh = $h1 - $h2;
$dw = $w1 - $w2;
$dist = sqrt($dh*$dh + $dw*$dw);
```

Note that you may get a non-integer result.

If you're interested in the [Manhattan Distance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) you would just do

```
$dist = abs($h1 - $h2) + abs($w1 - $w2);
```